# About updating a fork

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm pretty new to working with git (github), and here is my scenario:

- I have forked an android project and cloned it locally
- I'm using android studio, and when I use "Update Project", it show up a table which has 2 options:

```
Merge incoming changes into the current branch
```

or

```
Rebase the current branch on top of incoming changes
```

I chose the "merge" option, but it overwrite my local changes which hasn't been pushed to github. So, any way to update project but not affecting local changes? Please tell me a little bit more details in your solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit your changes locally before doing this.  You can then do the update without pushing your changes to GitHub.

Comment: So, after that, I want to push it to Github, will it push _all of my code and update changes_ *OR* only _my code with non-updated changes_?

Comment: Doing a push after this will push the current state of your local repository to remote.  In order to minimise unwanted overwriting of other users' changes, it is always wise to first pull/rebase then push very soon after.   Not doing things this way can result in messy merges.